# SignalR Azure Active Directory authorization issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, signalr

I have an app that is hosted under the azure app service. The app builds on ASP.NET MVC with Angular JS (SPA).

The hosted app is protected with Azure Active Directory authentication. And afterward, I integrated SignalR (2.0.4) into the same application.

SignalR is working correctly on the same site, but when trying to connect the SignalR hub connection from another app it just breaks and redirects me to the MS login page, as a web app service protected with required Azure Active Directory authentication.

I did try to send `Authorization: "Bearer <token>"` and `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN` in the request header but it did not work.

My SPA (AngularJs) and SignalR code are in the same project.